# How to create a "datasheet-like" list view to update a checkbox in multiple rows?

Tags: security, datasheet, list-view-web-part

I am using draft item security on a forms library to only allow the creator of a form and a user with "edit items" permissions to view a form in the library.

I would like to provide the user with "edit items" permission to be able to view the library in a datasheet view so that they may easily update a yes/no column for multiple items. Unfortunately as I am using draft item security it appears that this view is read only.

Is it possible to create a custom list view to achieve the same functionality and if so does anyone have any pointers to get started?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using SharePoint Designer and the Data View Web Part. You might not even need jQuery.

Check out Laura Rogers' blog - she has some very excellent step-by-step screencasts.
http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Pages/Data%20View%20Web%20Part%20Screencasts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Sharepoint Designer in your environment? You could create a webpart, add some jQuery and effectively do what you are looking for. You could still do it without designer but it would take more work.